# Python - Extract Main Language Code from HTTP / Browser

Tags: python, django, http-accept-language

I need a way to determine the main language set in a browser. I found a really great solution for PHP but unfortunately I'm using Django / Python.

I think the information is within the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE attribute of the HTTP Request.

Any ideas or ready-made functions for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`request.META` dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META):

```
print request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
```

The [WebOb project](http://webob.org/), a lightweight web framework, includes a handy [accept parser](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webob/en/latest/api/webob.html#module-webob.acceptparse) that you could reuse in this case:

```
from webob.acceptparse import Accept

language_accept = Accept(request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])
print language_accept.best_match(('en', 'de', 'fr'))
print 'en' in language_accept
```

Note that installing the WebOb package won't interfere with Django's functionality, we are just re-using a class from the package here that happens to be very useful.

A short demo is always more illustrative:

```
>>> header = 'en-us,en;q=0.5'
>>> from webob.acceptparse import Accept
>>> lang = Accept(header)
>>> 'en' in lang
True
>>> 'fr' in lang
False
>>> lang.best_match(('en', 'de', 'fr'))
'en'
```

Comment: i know this but I need a way to detect the main language. Mostly the `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` is a string containing different languages etc

Comment: Just be aware that the client may not always pass `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` and even if it does, its value may not be correct. The most fool-proof method is and always will be to let the user explicitly pick their language.

Comment: its just a minor feature on my website. if i get the code, its nice. if not, i just use german or english...

Answer (score 2):

This is a function that i used and that is my creation self.

```
def language(self):
        if 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' in self._request.META:
            lang = self._request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
            return str(lang[:2])
        else:
            return 'en'
```

Just call it.